# How to distinguish between array and non-array output

Tags: php

I'm working on a way to pull a list of files from a query and am having trouble when the query returns more than one file.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);


static $fileCount = 0;
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

ob_start(); 


        $soapClient = new SoapClient("https://ip_address:8443/CDRonDemandService/services/CDRonDemand?wsdl", 
array("login" => "login","password"=> "password","trace" => true, "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE)); 

        echo '<pre>';   

//THIS LINE IS FOR A MANUAL PULL OF THE LIST.  ENTER THE START AND END DATES AS NEEDED

        $data = $soapClient->get_file_list("beginning_range","end_range","1");

//If $data only contains one object, execute this;

    if (count($data) === 1)
        {
        var_dump($data);
        $name = $data->FileName;
        echo '<tr><td>'. $name .'</td></tr>';
        $fileCount = '1';
        }

//Otherwise, execute this if $data contains any other number 
    else
        {
        sort($data->FileName);
        var_dump($data);
        foreach($data->FileName as $name)
                    {
                    echo '<tr><td>' . $name . '</td></tr><br>'; 
                    $fileCount++; 
                    }
        }

echo "<TABLE>";
$content = ob_get_clean();
echo "Number of CDR Files <b>" . $fileCount . "</b><br />";
echo $content;


?>
```

This code works okay when the output of a query contains a single file.  This is the output;

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["FileName"]=>
  string(40) "file_1"
}
file_1
```

But when the output contains multiple files (an array), this is the output;

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["FileName"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(40) "file_1"
    [1]=>
    string(40) "file_2"
  }
}


Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/test.php on line 49

Array
```

If I remove the code in the if statement and leave only the code in the else statement, I'm able to pull the list of files;

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["FileName"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(40) "file_1"
    [1]=>
    string(40) "file_2"
  }
}
file_1
file_2
```

It looks to me that the If/Else structure isn't right, but I'm not sure how to go about correcting it.  Also, the var_dump statements are only there for troubleshooting, to show that I am actually pulling information, I will remove it later.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `count($data)` is always equal to 1. You're trying to access an array with `$data->FileName`. Which is throwing the error

```
if (count($data)) {
    if(is_array($data->FileName)) {
        foreach($data->FileName as $name) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . $name . '</td></tr><br>'; 
            $fileCount++;
        }
    } else {
        echo '<tr><td>'. $data->FileName .'</td></tr>';
        $fileCount++;
    }
} else {
    echo "no files!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Bankzilla.  Very help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will work if you change

```
if (count($data) === 1)
```

to

```
if (count($data->Filename) === 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
if (count($data) === 1) { ... }
```

to this:

```
if ( is_array($data->Filename) ) { ... }
```

[documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)